# How to re-create tree whose inorder traversal is stored in the file

Tags: c++

A special type of tree is given, Where all leaf are marked with distinct symbols and all others nodes are marked with dummy character 0. every node can have 0 or at most 2 nodes. Trees inorder traversal is written to file. Please give a algorithm to build tree from this traversal.

Comment: Take an example tree, iterate over it in inorder traversal, write down the nodes in order of how you reach them. Now go in reverse, should help you in creating the tree.

Comment: It's much better if you attempt the question and list the algorithm, explaining what bits you think work, and what bits don't, how you've tried to fix it or what you're unsure of.  People don't mind helping, but generally only after some attempt's been made....

Comment: @DumbCoder: it won't work. he wants the exact same tree, which cannot be done with only inorder traversal, but maybe the additional information (which node is leaf, and which is not) might come handy here.

Comment: @Deepak: is it homework? why is the c++ tag? it seems you need an algorithm, am I right?

Comment: what have you accomplished so far?

Comment: @amit, it is not a homework.Actually i am implementing huffman encoding algorithm and i have created the huffman tree.Now i am writing the inorder traversal of tree into file. But while decoding i have to construct the same tree again with the given property

Answer (score 4):

the problem as explained in the question is unsolveable, because **there can be more then one tree for a given in-order traversal**, even if the leaves are well known. (in the example attached, the in order for both trees is 1,2,3,4,5 and 1,3,5 are leaves in both).

you might want to store both **inorder** traversal and **pre-prder** traversal, and from there, there is a simple recursive algorithm to reconstruct the tree:

```
reconstruct(List preOrder,List inOrder):
   if preOder.empty() == true:
          return nil
   root.value<-preOrder[0]
   left_in = inOrder.filter(left,root) (*) 
   left_pre = preOrder.filter(left,root) (*) 
   root.left = reconstruct(left_pre,left_in)
   right_in = inOrder.filter(right,root) (*) 
   right_pre = preOrder.filter(right,root) (*) 
   root.right= reconstruct(right_pre,right_in)
   return root
```

(*) the filter finds all elements left/right to the root (in the in-order) and returns it, for pre-order it returns the same set of nodes in-order returned, but as they appear in the pre-order list.

attached: example described above:
[image]

**EDIT:** added stop condition for the recursive algorithm.

**EDIT 2:**

the filter will look something like that (pseudo code) (assuming each element is unique):

```
inOrderFilter(list,root):
  i <- 0
  left <- [] (empty list)
  right <- []
  while (list[i] != root):
    left.add(list[i])
    i <- i+1
  while (i < list.size):
    right.add(list[i[)
    i <- i+1
  return pair(left,right)

preOrderFilter(list,left_in,right_in):
  left <- []
  right <- []
  for each e in list:
    if e in left_in:
       left.add(e)
    else if e in right_in:
       right.add(e)
  return pair (left,right)
```

basically, for the left_in you need everything left of the root, and for right_in you need everything right of the root (left and right according to the in order list).

for left_pre, and right_pre: you need a permutations of left_in,right_in, each of them should have the same elements that XXX_in has, but they should retain the order they had in the original pre-order.

Comment: Actually if you know what are leaves (which the OP seems to know) and there are no nodes with single child, pre-order is enough to specify the tree.

Comment: @Jan: I don't think we can make the assumption about "no nodes with single child" (as the OP indicates there are "at most" 2 children for each non-leaf, and not exactly 2 nodes). This solution uses the minimum possible data on the specific problem to reconstruct the tree.

Comment: Can you provide more details for the algorithm? I am not getting how to use filter. I have to write the code in C++

Comment: @Deepak: see edit2, I added explanation about the filters, and how to implement it (pseudo code). converting it to c++ shouldn't be too hard.