# Traversal of trees

Tags: tree

What is the post-order traversal of a tree whose pre-order and in-order are:
PRE: ABDEHICFGJK
IN : DBHEIAFCJGK.
Can anyone draw the tree and explain it

Comment: If this is a homework.. please tag accordingly

Comment: is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Since this seems like homework - I won't give an answer - but a guideline:

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464507/how-to-re-create-tree-whose-inorder-traversal-is-stored-in-the-file)'s answer shows how to build a tree from in-order + pre-order traversals.

Follow the idea, and rebuild your tree.

Now, do a post order traversal, and this is your answer.