# Tree structure in C, for navigation in preorder depth-first manner

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree

How will you implement a tree structure in C for navigation in preorder depth-first manner?

Comment: A tree *is* a data structure.

Comment: I edited the question, is it more clear now ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [N-ary trees in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189855/n-ary-trees-in-c)

Comment: I'll write a simple struct with two pointers in it and implement preorder as a recursive function unless there are other constraints you are not telling. Is it you need help about the terminology, i.e. what is a tree, what is preorder traversal, what is depth-first search or I don't get the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tree can be represented by two arrays: one that holds pre-order traversal and the second hold in-order traversal. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464507/how-to-re-create-tree-whose-inorder-traversal-is-stored-in-the-file) discusses [among other things] how it can be done.

Since array traversal is usually faster then tree traversal [due to cache performance mainly], you can represent the tree as 2 arrays, and use the pre-order traversal one to iterate.