# BST to LinkList and back to same BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

Since I could not find anything useful so I am here to ask my question:

How can we convert the BST to a In-order linklist, and back to "same" BST, without using any extra space.

What I have tried so far (still doing though): I tried Morris Traversal to link up to the next in-order successor, 
but it is not able to connect for all the nodes, only working for the left subtree, and right subtree, not for the actual root of the tree.
Please suggest how can I convert Tree to Linked List and back to Same tree...

Comment: I think you don't need source code in the question, because the question is technology-agnostic and the source code is written in a given technology. Can you exclude the source code or to modify it to pseudo-code? Thanks (If you do one of these you will get an upvote from me for this question)

Comment: I we do not add code in the question, the People thinks that it is a home work question and they ask for : What have you tried, and downvote / close it.

Comment: That's why you can add pseudo-code or describe the ideas you've tried in words. Anyway, the question looks better now, so you get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution myself: below is the complete Java implementation
The logic + pseudo Code is as below
[1] Find the left most node in the tree, that will be the head of the LinkList, store it in the class

```
Node HeadOfList = null;
    findTheHeadOfInorderList (Node root)
    {
        Node curr = root;

        while(curr.left != null)
            curr = curr.left;

        HeadOfList = curr; // Curr will hold the head of the list

    }
```

[2] Do the reverse - inorder traversal of the tree to convert it to a LL on right pointer, and make sure the left pointer is always pointing to the parent of the node.

```
updateInorderSuccessor(Node root, Node inorderNext, Node parent)
{
    if(root != null) 
                 //Recursively call with the right child
            updateInorderSuccessor(root.right, inorderNext, root);

                // Update the in-order successor in right pointer
        root.right = inorderNext; 
        inorderNext = root;

                //Recursively call with the left child
        updateInorderSuccessor(root.left, inorderNext, root);

                // Update the parent in left pointer
        root.left = parent;
    }
}
```

[3] To convert it back :

Traverse the list and find the node with left pointer as null, 
Make it the root, break the link of this root in the linklist and also from its children...

Now the link list is broken into two parts one for left Subtree and one for right subtree, 
recursively find the roots in these two list and make them the left and right child, Please refer the function restoreBST()

```
Node restoreBST(Node head)
{
    if(head == null || (head.left == null && head.right == null)) return root;

    Node prev, root, right, curr;
            curr = head;

    // Traverse the list and find the node with left as null
    while(curr != null)
    {
        if(curr.left == null)
        {
            // Found the root of this tree
            root = curr;
                            // Save the head of the right list
            right = curr.right;
                            // Detach the children of the root just found, these will be updated later as a part of the recursive solution
            detachChildren(curr, head);
            break;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr.right;
    }

    // By now the root is found and the children of the root are detached from it.
    // Now disconnect the right pointer based connection in the list for the root node, so that list is broken in to two list, one for left subtree and one for right subtree
    prev.right = null;

    root.right = null;

    // Recursively call for left and right subtree

    root.left = restoreBST(head);
    root.right = restoreBST(right);

    //now root points to its proper children, lets return the root
    return root;
}
```

Logic to detach the children is simple : Iterate through the list and look for the nodes with left pointer equal to root.

```
private void detachChildren(AvlNode root, AvlNode head) {
    AvlNode curr = head;

    while(curr != null)
    {
        if(curr.left == root)
        {
            curr.left = null;
        }
        curr = curr.right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help me improve the answer and please upvote my answer so that I can accept it as a solution for the post, which will help other visitors to find an accepted solution.

Comment: Your answer will be upvoted if other people find it helpful, this doesn't work on request. You will be able to accept your own answer even if other people didn't upvote it, you can get upvotes from other questions or answers too. Also, I think your solution is too complicated. Of course I understand it, but the answer to the question is simpler. Also, your question was asked tagged as algorithm and binary-search-tree, so a Java implementation should not be accepted, because it's inconsistent with the requirements. Currently the only answer meeting the reuirements in this question is mine.

Comment: If you or other people edit their answers or create new answers which meet the reuirements in the question (for instance you simplify your solution and modify it to be algorithmical and technology-agnostic, not Java source code) then you will probably get some upvotes. So, if you want to accept your own answer, I think you should get some charisma by answering questions and you will have the right to do that. But if you accept your own question, please, either modify the requirements in the question or your answer to meet the requirements in the question.

Comment: Also, I think you should leave your question as it is, because it's more general than a Java question and your problem was independent from the technology used (Java), your problem was algorithmic.

Comment: @Lajos : I did not request for upvote, I requested to help me improve the answer in the first place.  I know I can accept my own answer after a day, But I did not want to do that until other accepts it OR suggest modification to be fair enough. And I would like to accept a working solution anyway at least for my questions, and this should be done by all the posters, so that the readers in the future get to see an accepted solution right away... Moreover a working code is always a better resource than a pseudo code. and understanding the code should not be a problem for the users here.

Comment: moreover, converting the java code to any other programming language should not be a problem, and considering the algorithmic nature of the question, I tried to summarize in a high level in my answer.. see the 3 points and small overview before starting the code. Lastly I think we both are diverting :)

Comment: I have simplified the code for BST to In-order LL conversion,

Comment: It's better to have a working code than pseudo-code? Are you serious? What will a Python or Visual Basic programmer understand from your code if they haven't used C-based programming languages yet? If somebody has to code this in SQL and didn't have the luck to meet C-based languages, what will he/she understand from your code? And, if you want a working code anyway, why don't you download a library and call its specific function which does this? Oh yeah, because you want to understand the algorithm. So this is an algorithmical question. Then it should be language-agnostic.

Comment: It's good to see your dedication to learn, I'm encouraging this, but you should know that when you or anybody else needs ideas, the answer should be language-agnostic and if you need a solution to a given problem in a given language, then source code is best. If you give someone a fish, you feed him for a day. If you teach someone to fish, you feed him for a lifetime.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad : I have further edited the answer and simplified with the plain English details and commented and removed the unwanted lines from the code, I hope you will like it better :).

Comment: Nope, this is still Java code posted as an answer to an algorithmical question.

Answer (score 0):

To store a tree in lists - you need at least two lists: one for pre-order traversal, and the other for in-order traversal.

Luckily - since the tree is a BST, the in-order traversal is just the sorted list.

So, you can store the pre-order traversal (You can try doing it in-place) and by sorting the elements in re-construction, you can get the in-order traversal.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6464507/572670) discusses how to reconstruct a tree from the inorder and pre-order traversals of it.

Comment: No this is not something I am looking for as we have to do it in-place, without using extra space

Answer (score 0):

Binary Search Tree to List:

```
subTreeToList(node)
    if (node.hasLeft()) then subTreeToList(node.left, list)
    list.add(node.Value)
    if (node.hasRight()) subTreeToList(node.right, list)
    end if
subTreeToList end

treeToList(tree)
    subTreeToList(tree.root)
treeToList end

list <- new List()
treeToList(tree)
```

You need to implement the idea above into your solution, if you are working with object-oriented technologies, then list and trees should be data members, otherwise they should be passed to the functions as references.

You can build back your tree knowing that insertion in the tree looks like this:

```
Insert(tree, value)
    if (tree.root is null) then
        tree.createRoot(value)
    else
        node <- tree.root
        while (((node.value < value) and (node.hasRight())) or ((node.value > value) and (node.hasLeft())))
            if ((node.value < value) and (node.hasRight())) then node <- node.right()
            else node <- node.left()
            end if
        while end
        if (node.value > value) then node.createLeft(value)
        else node.createRight(value)
        end if
    end if
insert end
```

You just have to traverse your list sequentially and call the function implemented based on my pseudo-code above. Good luck with your homework.

Comment: I could not understand your answer for "Binary Search Tree to List:" could you please explain it with more details

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check to see whether it's more helpful now. If not, please tell me where to improve my representation. Help me to help you.

Comment: Couple of points : With Link list I meant to be In-order sorted LL, I have updated that in question, your code is converting to pre-order LL..  and second: The conversion should take place in place no new memory should be use except some local var etc, basically all we have to do is manipulate the pointers...

Comment: I've edited my answer, it will be ordered ascending, so your first point is covered from now on in my answer. As of your second point, it was not specified that the list and the tree are already existing, but you can set values instead of adding new nodes, that should be pretty trivial, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution for BST to LL, hope you find it useful.

```
    Node BSTtoLL(BST root) {

        if(null == root) return null;

        Node l = BSTtoLL(root.left);
        Node r = BSTtoLL(root.right);

        Node l1 = null;
        if(null != l) {
            l1 = l;
            while(null != l.left) { l = l.left; }
            l.left = root;
            l.right = null;
        }
        if(null != r) {
            root.left = r;
            root.right = null;
        }

        if(null != l1) return l1;
        return root;
    }
```

Comment: Have not tested it, and so I am very open for criticism :)